ScrollBar acting strange for the same sandbox instance on different PCs using visualforce
Ok, so there is a peculiar situation I'm encountering here.
I have a VF page with a table that overflows when it exceeds a certain width or height. Now, everything is working fine.
One of my friends and I are using the same sandbox instance on which we test this code and see its results. On my PC, the scrollbars and overflows are working fine. But on my friend's PC, the scrollbar isn't appearing, and on overflow, the data just gets cut out. My friend is from the US, and I'm from Pakistan.
Things I tried:

Even though it can't be a timezone issue I changed my timezone to US but the situation persists.

I had overflows set before, but now I'm going with the table's default overflow property and it's working for me

We have also a production org, and the same thing happens there. For my friend, the instance shows strange behavior of having 2-3 scrollbars at one time or no scrolling function at all and for me, everything works as smoothly as it should.


Please: I am new to Visualforce, so if there's something that isn't up to the mark, be kind and guide me. Thank you.
Following is my code:
<apex:page standardController="Building__c" extensions="BuildingController" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
<head>
    <style>
        tr{
        border-top: 1px solid black;
        }
        tr:last-child{
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        }
        <!--
        td{
        border-left: 1px solid black;
        }
        -->
        
        tr td:last-child{
        border-right: 1px solid black;
        }

        table{
            width: -webkit-fill-available;}

        body{
            padding:0 !important;
        }
        
        tr,td{
        width:100%;
        }
        td{
        display:flex;
        flex-direction:column;
        text-align: center;
        justify-content: center;
        word-wrap:break-word;
        height: 80px;
        }
        
        tr{
        display:flex;
        align-items:center;
        line-height: 20px;
        }
        
        .legendStack{
        display:flex;
        flex-direction:row;
        position:absolute;
        width: 100%;
        }
        
        
        .legendStack div{
        width:10%;
        height: 25px;
        text-align:center;
        padding-top:10px
        }           

        .floor-cell {              
            min-width: 2%;
            max-width: 2%;
            flex-basis: 2%;
            text-align: center;
        }     

        .vertical-text {
            writing-mode: vertical-rl;
            transform: rotate(260deg);
            margin-left:-2px;
        }

        .legendFixItem {
            line-height: 10px;
            padding-top: 0px !important;
            height: 35px !important;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-content: center;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr style="border-left: 1px solid black;">
            <td style="height: 30px;">{!resp.NameAndAddressField}</td>
        </tr>
        <apex:repeat value="{!resp.suiteInfoList}" var="cdata">
            <tr style="min-height:10px; height:auto;overflow-y:hidden; border-left: 1px solid black;">
                
                    <td class="floor-cell" style="{!IF(cdata.styleClass == 'vertical-text', 'transform: rotate(279deg);', '')}">
                        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!cdata.styleClass == ''}">
                            <span>{!cdata.FloorNumber}</span>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!cdata.styleClass == 'vertical-text'}">
                            <span class="{!cdata.styleClass}">{!cdata.FloorNumber}</span>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                    </td>
                
                
                    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!cdata.hasSuites}">
                        <apex:repeat value="{!cdata.individualSuiteList}" var="idata">
                            <td style="overflow:hidden; 
                                       background:{!IF(idata.gradient == '', idata.color, 
                                       'repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, ' + idata.gradient + ',' + idata.gradient + ' 2px, #dddddd 1px, #dddddd 18px)')};
                                       color:{!idata.textcolor};
                                       width:{!cdata.width}; 
                                       border-left: 1px solid black;
                                       height:{!cdata.height}px;">
                        
                                <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!idata.Status == 'Vacant'}">
                                    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!idata.Availability == 'Unavailable'}">
                                        <span>Vacant - {!idata.Availability}</span>
                                    </apex:outputPanel>
                                    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!idata.Availability != 'Unavailable'}">
                                        <span>Vacant</span>
                                    </apex:outputPanel>
                                </apex:outputPanel>
                        
                                <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!idata.Status == 'Leased'}">
                                    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!NOT(ISBLANK(idata.Link))}">
                                        <span><apex:outputlink value="{!idata.Link}" style="background-color:{!idata.color};color:{!idata.textcolor};" target="_blank">{!idata.Name}</apex:outputlink>
                                            <apex:outputText style="background-color:{!idata.color};color:{!idata.textcolor};" rendered="{! idata.Link != null && idata.Link != ''}" value="{!idata.ListedBy}" />
                                        </span>
                                    </apex:outputPanel>
                                </apex:outputPanel>
                        
                                <div>
                                    <apex:outputlink value="{!idata.SuiteLink}" style="background-color:{!idata.color};color:{!idata.textcolor};" target="_blank">{!idata.SuiteNumber}</apex:outputlink>
                                </div>
                        
                                <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!NOT(idata.SuiteRSF == '')}">
                                    <apex:outputText style="background-color:{!idata.color};color:{!idata.textcolor};" value="{!IF(idata.Availability == 'Available', 
                                        IF(idata.SuiteRSF == idata.AvailableRSF, 
                                            idata.SuiteRSF + ' RSF', 
                                            idata.SuiteRSF + ' RSF (' + idata.AvailableRSF + ' RSF Available)'), 
                                        '')}">
                                    </apex:outputText>
                                    <apex:outputText style="background-color:{!idata.color};color:{!idata.textcolor};" value="{!IF(idata.Availability != 'Available', idata.SuiteRSF + ' RSF', '')}">
                                    </apex:outputText>
                                </apex:outputPanel>
                        
                                <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!idata.SuiteRSF == ''}">
                                    <span style="background-color:{!idata.color};color:{!idata.textcolor};">TBD RSF</span>
                                </apex:outputPanel>
                        
                                <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!idata.Status == 'Leased'}">
                                    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!idata.LandlordUse == 'Landlord'}">
                                        <span style="background-color:{!idata.color};color:{!idata.textcolor};">Landlord</span>
                                    </apex:outputPanel>
                        
                                    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!idata.LandlordUse == 'Property Manager' && NOT(ISBLANK(idata.SuiteLEXP))}">
                                        <span style='line-height: 12px; background-color:{!idata.color};color:{!idata.textcolor};'>{!idata.SuiteLEXP} - Property Manager</span>
                                    </apex:outputPanel>
                        
                                    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!idata.LandlordUse == 'Property Manager' && ISBLANK(idata.SuiteLEXP)}">
                                        <span style='line-height: 12px; background-color:{!idata.color};color:{!idata.textcolor};'>Property Manager</span>
                                    </apex:outputPanel>
                        
                                    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!idata.LandlordUse != 'Landlord' && idata.LandlordUse != 'Property Manager' && NOT(ISBLANK(idata.SuiteLEXP))}">
                                        <span style="background-color:{!idata.color};color:{!idata.textcolor};">{!idata.SuiteLEXP}</span>
                                    </apex:outputPanel>
                                </apex:outputPanel>
                            </td>
                        </apex:repeat>
                        
            </apex:outputPanel>   
            <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!NOT(cdata.hasSuites)}">
                <td colspan="10" style="text-align: center; height: 80px; border-right:1px solid black; border-left:1px solid black;">
                    No Data
                </td>
            </apex:outputPanel>
            </tr>
        </apex:repeat>
    </table>
    <br/>

    <div class="legendStack">
        <div class="legendFixItem" style="background-color:#dddddd;color:black;border-top:thin solid black; border-bottom:thin solid black; border-left:thin solid black;">Available Direct</div>
        <div class="legendFixItem" style="background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, #000000, #000000 2px, #dddddd 1px, #dddddd 18px);color:black;border-top:thin solid black; border-bottom:thin solid black; border-left:thin solid black;"><span style="background-color:#dddddd; width: min-content;">Available Sublease</span></div>
        <div class="legendFixItem" style="background-color:black;color:white;border-top:thin solid black; border-bottom:thin solid black; border-left:thin solid black;">Landlord or<br/> Prop Mgmt</div>
        <div style="background-color:#ffffff;color:red;border-top:thin solid black; border-bottom:thin solid black; border-left:thin solid black;">Expired</div>
        
        
        <apex:repeat value="{!resp.yearColors}" var="year">
            <div style="background-color:{!resp.yearColors[year]}; color:{!resp.yearTextColors[year]}; border-top:thin solid black; border-bottom:thin solid black; border-left:thin solid black;">
                {!year}
            </div>
        </apex:repeat>
    </div>
</body>
</apex:page>


What browsers and browser versions do you use? Same thing happens with other browsers? Has any of you enabled "Development Mode" in user settings? Are you sys admins and have you tried logging on as the other user?
